# How to fade between divs on click, starting with display none?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across this JSFiddle online whilst searching for a solution. It almost does what I need except I need to start with the div being hidden. I've tried playing around with it but being new to JS I've not had much luck.

I thought I'd put this here as a starting point to see if anyone could advise on the route I would need to take?

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        var $this = $(this);
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#menu li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:4px solid #efefef;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu .current {
    border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;
}
ul#menu li:hover {
    border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;
}
ul#menu li a {
    padding:2px 2px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#68759c;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color:#8895b8;
    border:none;
}
#div1 {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<div class="pbox" id="div1">First Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">Second Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">Third Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">Fourth Div</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `display: none;` in css to an element which you want to be hidden.

And remove `class="active"` from first `li` so that it's not chosen.

And modify js a little bit. See your function only shows a div if previously it hid. And if you start with all hidden it won't hide anything therefore it won't show anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
  $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    var $this = $(this);
    // fade out all open subcontents
    var visibleElements = $('.pbox:visible');
    if (visibleElements.length <= 0) {
        $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      visibleElements.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #efefef;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu .current {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3d496a;
}

ul#menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3d496a;
}

ul#menu li a {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #68759c;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: #8895b8;
  border: none;
}

.pbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<div class="pbox" id="div1">First Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">Second Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">Third Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">Fourth Div</div>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to hide all the divs on click anywhere else here is how to:

It's actually pretty easy.

We bind `click` event to document and check what was clicked.

If it was div with content (`#div1`, `#div2` etc.) or if it is menu element we do not want to hide the div, but else we do.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("pbox") && $(e.target).closest("#menu").length <= 0) {
      $('.pbox').fadeOut('slow');
      $("#menu .current").removeClass("current");
    }
  });
```

[`e.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) returns an element which (in this case) was clicked. If it has class `pbox` it means this is a div with content.

Second condition is menu element. If [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

returns an element with `id="menu"` it means that we clicked on an element inside the menu.

Notice the exclamation mark. It means that if the condition is false return true. So if we **did not** click the div with content **and** if we **did not** click menu element then we hide the div.

I hope you understand what I mean :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    var $this = $(this);
    // fade out all open subcontents
    var visibleElements = $('.pbox:visible');
    if (visibleElements.length <= 0) {
      $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
      visibleElements.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
      });
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass("pbox") && $(e.target).closest("#menu").length <= 0) {
      $('.pbox').fadeOut('slow');
      $("#menu .current").removeClass("current");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #efefef;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul#menu .current {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3d496a;
}

ul#menu li:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #3d496a;
}

ul#menu li a {
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: #68759c;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  color: #8895b8;
  border: none;
}

.pbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<div class="pbox" id="div1">First Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">Second Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">Third Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">Fourth Div</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this and for explaining it to me. I don't suppose it's a quick fix if I wanted all divs to hide on click of anywhere else on the screen?

Comment: @user2498890 It's not really difficult, I;ll edit my answer to show you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me!

Answer (score 1):

i just delete the class "current". but first div still appear, so i create another div, empty, and it works :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
        var $this = $(this);
        // fade out all open subcontents
        $('.pbox:visible').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#menu li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:4px solid #efefef;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu .current {
    border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;
}
ul#menu li:hover {
    border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;
}
ul#menu li a {
    padding:2px 2px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#68759c;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color:#8895b8;
    border:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<div class="pbox" id="div5"></div>
<div class="pbox" id="div1">First Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div2">Second Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div3">Third Div</div>
<div class="pbox" id="div4">Fourth Div</div>
```

Comment: Nice snippet bra

Answer (score 0):

Delete `class="current"`, so none is active at the beginning,

and then set the first div to `display:none;`

Comment: I did try that but this doesn't seem to work. See my code above as I've update it.

Comment: Check @Krzysztof Janiszewski's answer. Should be what you seek